# Quartz Scheduler implementation for JBoss EAP 7.0.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating an application built over JBoss 4.2.1 server to JBoss EAP 7.0.0 server. In JBoss 4.2.1 the quartz would use the MBean implementation and would be started and initialized using () followed by the property. The reason this was done was the start and stop of the Mbean can be controlled by HASingleton service in a clustered node. This has been removed in EAP 7.0.0 server as it was not following J2EE convention ([link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/153373)).  The alternative is to use EJB scheduling service as recommended in the post. But we cannot do that as it leads to major change in the business logic, which would be not appreciated here. Any solution recommendation to resolve this issue.

I have tried to invoke the bean by placing the scheduler instance in a singleton bean. It is working but has to be extended to work in a JBoss cluster node configuration wherein only one instance should be started and the other node can access this instance for reporting web view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JBoss EAP 7 is Java EE 7 so you could use the concurrency utilities (JSR 236) too. Maybe it can be used with Quartz I'm not sure. See https://developers.redhat.com/quickstarts/sandbox/managedexecutorservice/ for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but looking at integrating quartz in a cluster environment where only one instance of scheduler should start on one node only even if 2 instances deployed. Also, the object should be access able by the second where is not started so to get status information by web view.